# why use a second column of a key in where is so slow to return result

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table op_log , all record count is `47362198`. and have below colums and index,

```
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`operate_result` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`create_user_id` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL

 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `user_id` (`user_id`,`create_user_id`),
```

And actually `user_id` is null, only used `create_user_id`, first I execute below sql

```
select * from op_log where operate_result like 'foo%'  order by id desc limit 10;
......
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Then I add a condition of `create_user_id`,

```
select * from op_log where operate_result like 'foo%' and create_user_id = '4987bcbabc7530ee4c777038184d364b'  order by id desc limit 10;
```

very strange it seems it will execute forever, I have to CTRL+C to stop it, then I add another condition of user_id(actually user_id never used so it's null)

```
select * from op_log where operate_result like 'foo%' and create_user_id = '4987bcbabc7530ee4c777038184d364b'  and user_id is null order by id desc limit 10;
...
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

So why only have `create_user_id` in where could execute for ever, but either not have it or both have it with `user_id` could execute quickly?

```
explain select * from op_log where operate_result like 'foo%'  order by id desc limit 10;
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | op_log | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL |   10 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+

explain select * from op_log where operate_result like 'foo%' and create_user_id = '4987bcbabc7530ee4c777038184d364b'  order by id desc limit 10;
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | op_log | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL |   10 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+

explain select * from op_log where operate_result like 'foo%' and create_user_id = '4987bcbabc7530ee4c777038184d364b'  and user_id is null order by id desc limit 10;
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref         | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | op_log | ref  | user_id       | user_id | 396     | const,const |    2 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Kenney's answer is probably the main one you are looking for.)

`select * from op_log where operate_result like 'foo%'  order by id desc limit 10;`

should not have gone fast, but possibly did because most of the *last* (as in `order by id desc`) several rows satisfied `where operate_result like 'foo%'`.  If you change `foo%` to something less common, you will probably see a significant slowdown.

[*More on building indexes*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

Comment: I think you are right, when I just have `create_user_id` in where, and limit result count to 2 , e.g. `select * from op_log where create_user_id = '4987bcbabc7530ee4c777038184d364b' order by id desc limit 2` it's fast returned, but when changed to 3 then it becomes very slow. but I compare the id of the return record with the current id of the table found their interval is 90201, and I think it's so long, and is a little confused.

Answer (score 1):

The index you have on that table,

```
KEY `user_id` (`user_id`,`create_user_id`),
```

is a compound-key. It only works to speed things up if you specify conditions on both `user_id` and `create_user_id` in your `WHERE` clause. 
The query

```
select * from op_log where operate_result like 'foo%' 
and create_user_id = '4987bcbabc7530ee4c777038184d364b'
order by id desc limit 10;
```

cannot use that index because there is no condition on `user_id`, and so MySQL will have to check all 47 million rows.

What you'll want to do is add an index (key) on the `create_user_id` column, since you don't care about the always-null `user_id`:

```
ALTER TABLE op_log ADD INDEX (create_user_id);
```

Comment: (I am upvoting your answer because of good content, though not enough to get the "approved answer" points.)